# Ubuntu vi Acting Strange

Tags: ubuntu, vim, text-editing

I just installed Ubuntu Server 8 and found vi to be acting strangely (compared to vi on Fedora, CentOS and OSX).

When I use the 'a' command to enter text, pressing the arrow keys results in "C", "D", "B" and "A" to get entered. This makes editing almost impossible..

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're probably using the vim-tiny editor that doesn't support arrow key navigation in insert mode; Ubuntu 8.04 doesn't have the `vim` package installed. Install this, and update your default version of vi:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
sudo update-alternatives --config vi
```

Select "vim.basic". You may also want to do this for editor (replace vi in the command above with editor) so the default editor called by other programs (like visudo) is also the right version of vim.

I also advise getting in the habit of hitting ESC from insert mode and using `hjkl` navigation common to Vi/Vim, rather than using the arrow keys.

Comment: It may also be actual `vi` instead of `vim`.  Being a server they tend to ship with bare minimum.  `hjkl` is the way to go.  =-]

Comment: @jack m.: jtimberman's correct, ubuntu will install the `vim-tiny` package by default.  i think this version of vim *is* compiled to *act like* `vi`, so there won't be much (if any) difference between it and actual `vi`.

Answer (score 7):

another option is to remove vim-tiny:

```
sudo apt-get remove vim-tiny
```

and then reinstall vim:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: +1, just because I don't see any reason to keep vim-tiny in the system anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
aptitude install vim-full
```

The first thing I do on a new ubuntu install.

Comment: That will install the vim-gnome package, which is probably undesirable on 'server' systems.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
:set nocompatible
```

If it works you may consider putting it into your `.exrc` (w/o colon).

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to do some configuration:

```
$ cp /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/vimrc_example.vim ~/.vimrc
$ vim !$    # and adapt it to your needs
```

The example vimrc has some useful settings and is a good starting point.

(note that you have to adapt the path for other systems, this is debian/ubuntu specific. On Systems that follow upstream vim installation more closely, it is `/usr/share/vim/vimrc_example.vim`)